# Problems with android fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

In MainActivity, I have a method ("saveTask") to add a task to the appropriate adapter. Here the relevant part of your code.

```
    ViewPager pager = null;
MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager
    this.pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Set a custom animation
    this.pager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPagerTransformer());

    // Create an adapter with the fragments we show on the ViewPager
    this.adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    this.adapter.addFragment(InActivityPageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.red), 0));
    this.adapter.addFragment(ListActivitiesPageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.white), 1));
    this.pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void saveTask(Task task){
    ListActivitiesPageFragment fragment = (ListActivitiesPageFragment) this.adapter.getItem(1);
    fragment.addTask(task);
}
```

The "addTask" method is invoked from the main, are here:

```
public void addTask(Task task) {

    if (task == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    listTasks.add(task);

    // Importante: notificar que ha cambiado el dataset
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at timetrack.app.MainActivity.saveTask(MainActivity.java:62)
```

Class MyFragmentPagerAdapter:

```
 public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

// List of fragments which are going to set in the view pager widget
List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragments.add(fragment);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    return this.fragments.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Página " + (position + 1);
}
```

Comment: And where you create your pagerAdapter?

Comment: I add the code of the Adapter

Comment: Where do you instantiate the `pagerAdapter`? I can only see `adapter` in your code above, not `pagerAdapter`.

Comment: Right. Now I use the adapter, but the error persists.

Comment: Which error now? Still NullPointer?

Comment: Yes. I refresh the code too. NullPointer. In this line:   ListActivitiesPageFragment fragment = (ListActivitiesPageFragment) adapter.getItem(1);

Comment: The `adapter` variable is a local variable (i.e, you defined it inside of a method), therefore other methods (your `saveTask()` method) cannot use it-- it is null.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `adapter` variable you instantiate is defined within your method, so it is a local variable. This means other methods cannot use that particular instance.

You need to create (if you haven't already) a class variable called `adapter`. Then instead of writing:

```
MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
        getSupportFragmentManager());
```

you should write:

```
this.adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
        getSupportFragmentManager());
```

This will allow other methods within your class to access the adapter variable.

Comment: I changed the code, I think, as you indicated me. But the error is still the same and in the same line.